# Remote powershell sessions can only be established with interactively entered credentials?

Tags: powershell, session, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to automate a powershell script which gathers data from O365.  I've got a special limited user setup with the privileges required on O365 and also with local logon allowed on the server so that I can "run-as" that user (which I do for all the scripts below.  I have verified different, expected errors when running as other users).

The script works fine interactively when credentials are set like this and the session opened:

```
$cred  = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic –AllowRedirection
```

However, if I create the credentials file for automation with:

```
Get-Credential | Export-Clixml -Path C:\batch\${env:USERNAME}_cred.xml
```

And then access from the script via:

```
$cred = Import-Clixml -Path C:\batch\${env:USERNAME}_cred.xml
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic –AllowRedirection
```

The credential file load appears to succeed.  I then get "Access Denied" on the session open, and then of course the rest of the script fails due to the session being null.  I'm cutting and pasting the password in all cases (plus have tried many, MANY times including hand typing) so I don't think it's a simple typo issue.  Seems more like something I'm fundamentally misunderstanding about powershell.  Ultimately I'd like to not just have the credentials automated, but also have it run from task scheduler if there's any special settings above and beyond that I also need.

Comment: If you import the file in an interactive session and check the saved password (use the GetNetworkCredential method on the pscredential object) is the password the same? I'm not sure if you can actually just export a securestring with export-clixml.

Comment: Are you using different hosts or users when you try to import/export the file?  The password is encrypted by DPAPI and is unique to a **user and host** combination.

Comment: @bluuf If I Write-Host the $cred.Username it comes out correct.  Write-Host on $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password though does not return the password.  I'm actually getting a section of code from an entirely different powershell script in the same directory!

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Same host, same user.

Comment: If that's the case, there's something missing from your question because I'm not able to repro your issue.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I can reproduce locally here with just the code snippets above, there's nothing else required from the complete script.

Comment: What version of powershell and OS?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Windows Server 2012R2 x64 DataCenter with Powershell 5.1 B14409 R1018

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong from your code from PowerShell perspective. I have tested the way you are creating credentials within a company domain and I was able to create new session by importing credential `XML` file that was created by exporting the credentials the way you did. I then assume it might be `MS Exchange` related.

I can suggest alternatives for you to try:

```
# First we need to get the encrypted password:
$TempCred = Get-Credential
# provide credentials to the prompt

# now the encryption to be saved in a file
$TempCred.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content C:\mypass.txt
```

This was the encrypted version of your password is saved as a text.

In your automation script you can now do this:

```
 $username = "yourusername"
 $password = Get-Content C:\mypass.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
 $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($username, $password)
 $session = New-PSSession -Credential $cred .....
```

I am not sure if this works in your case, it worked in my company domain. Once again it worked for me the `XML` version too. I am just providing alternatives to try if you are not keen to find out as to why the `XML` way did not work.

Comment: We did actually get it working, but I don't remember how.  I've been meaning to try to reproduce the solution sequence and post up here, but just haven't had time yet.

Comment: I am glad that it worked, but also I am keen to know your solution.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch ~ Do you remember how you got it working?

Comment: @InteXX Well, one of my users just mentioned a couple weeks ago that he hadn't seen any of the reports from this in a couple months...  I went and checked, and sure enough it no longer works.  Did a quick reset of credentials in case that was it, but no change.  Unfortunately, with my other break/fix and project load I haven't had time to put serious work on this again quite yet.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch ~ Well now isn't that a coincidence! Hope you're able to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working, in my environment at least, by including a call to `Import-PSSession`:

```
$Credential = Import-Clixml -Path D:\Modules\O365Credentials.xml
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $Credential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking
Get-Mailbox
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the account in question have MFA enabled? If so, you might try [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Connect-to-Exchange-Online-7d7365e0).

This script:

- Downloads Exchange Online Remote PowerShell Module
- Installs Exchange Online PowerShell Module
- Connects Exchange Online PowerShell using MFA

Or, you can perform these manually. More information, including a detailed walk-through, is available here:

https://o365reports.com/2019/04/17/connect-exchange-online-using-mfa/